# How to filter Select based on another Select value

Tags: reactjs

I have got an issue with filtering Select menu based on another select value. The second select menu should be updated on every change of the first select. What actually happens is that the second select value if filters based on the **Previous** value of the first select and not at the moment. Thank you in advance !

```
const [selectedManufacturer, setSelectedManufacturer] = useState("");
const [manufacturers, setManufacturers] = useState([]);
const [modelsMenu, setModelsMenu] = useState([]);
const [models, setModels] = useState([]);

const handleManufacturerChange = (event) => {
    setSelectedManufacturer(event.target.value);
    let chosenID = manufacturers.find(
        (manufacturer) =>
            manufacturer.Manufacturer_Name === selectedManufacturer
    )
    chosenID = (chosenID) ? chosenID.Manufacturer_ID : 'undefined';
    setModelsMenu(models.filter(model => chosenID === model.Manufacturer_ID));
};

return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
        <Grid container spacing={1}>
            <Grid item xs={12} md={2} className="register-label">
                <FormLabel>יצרן הרכב</FormLabel>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} md={4}>
                <Select
                    value={selectedManufacturer}
                    onChange={handleManufacturerChange}
                    className={classes.formControl}
                >
                    {manufacturers.map((manufacturer, index) => {
                        return (
                            <MenuItem
                                value={manufacturer.Manufacturer_Name}
                                key={index}
                            >
                                {manufacturer.Manufacturer_Name}
                            </MenuItem>
                        );
                    })}
                </Select>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} md={2} className="register-label">
                <FormLabel>מודל הרכב</FormLabel>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} md={4}>
                <Select value="" className={classes.formControl}>
                    {modelsMenu.map((model, index) => {
                        return (
                            <MenuItem
                                value={model.Model_Name}
                                key={index}
                            >
                                {model.Model_Name}
                            </MenuItem>
                        );
                    })}
                </Select>
    </div>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Make modelsMenu like this:

```
const [modelsMenu, setModelsMenu] = useState({
option1:["option1","option2"],
option2:["option1","option2"],
option3:["option1","option2"]
})
```

Now make Second Select Menu like this:

```
Select value="" className={classes.formControl}>
                    {modelsMenu[selectedManufacturer].map((model, index) => {
                        return (
                            <MenuItem
                                value={model.Model_Name}
                                key={index}
                            >
                                {model.Model_Name}
                            </MenuItem>
                        );
                    })}
                </Select>
```

On changing the value from first Select, the second select will be updated with new options.

Answer (score 0):

there is a little mistake in your code, just update this find function

```
 let chosenID = manufacturers.find(
    (manufacturer) =>
        manufacturer.Manufacturer_Name === event.target.value
)
```

using useState "setSelectedManufacturer" will be async function and you can't get the updated value in the same function you are updating it, you can do that by using callback method